# Type Error when inputting positive integer

Tags: python

Here is my code, I keep getting error. I am able to sucessfully identiy non valid integers. However if I enter a positive one i receive this error TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.

```
inter=(input('Enter a positive integer:'))
if not inter.isdigit():
    print('You did not enter a valid input!')
else:
    if(inter%2==0):
        print('You entered an even number')
    elif(inter%7==0):
        print('You entered an odd number that is a multiple of 7')
    else:
        print('You entered an odd number that is NOT a multiple of 7')
```

Comment: `inter` is a string, as your use of `isdigit` suggests you know. `%` on a string is C-style formatting, not modulus.

Comment: Thank  you! However, I am still not sure what I would have to do to fix the problem

Comment: Convert the string into an integer before attempting mathematical operations on it.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Been trying to figure this out for hours!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
try:
    inter=int((input('Enter a positive integer:')))
    if(inter%2==0):
        print('You entered an even number')
    elif(inter%7==0):
        print('You entered an odd number that is a multiple of 7')
    else:
        print('You entered an odd number that is NOT a multiple of 7')
except:    
    print('You did not enter a valid input!')
```

This is a better way to see if the input is an int or not. The `try-except` statement handle any errors. If try encounters an error, then it will break out of that statement and do the except statement. So when the input is cast to an int, if the input is a string, it will throw an error.

Comment: Thank you! I am familiar with that method . However I had to use the isdigit function

Answer (score 0):

```
inter=(input('Enter a positive integer:'))
if not inter.isdigit():
print('You did not enter a valid input!')
else:
if(int(inter)%2==0):
    print('You entered an even number')
elif(int(inter)%7==0):
    print('You entered an odd number that is a multiple of 7')
else:
    print('You entered an odd number that is NOT a multiple of 7')
```